# DelayedJob email where to have 'who to email' logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, delayed-job

In my [app](http://shutterhire.com) I have certain events that trigger a lot of emails (~100). Obviously sending them immediately is not an option, so I'm using DelayedJob to queue them up and send them after the request is processed. I've now found that the logic to determine WHICH 100 people to email is heavy enough that it takes a while to run, so I'd like to DelayedJob that process as well. **Where should this logic go? (model? mailer?)** Sending mail from the model just feels wrong. Is there a best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a class that represents the job. Not a model class, not a controller class: a job class.

```
# app/jobs/mail_job.rb
class MailJob
  attr_accessor :first_option, :second_option

  def initialize(first_option, second_option)
    self.first_option = first_option
    self.second_option = second_option
  end

  def perform
    accounts = Account.where("some_key" => first_option).to_a
    # more complicated stuff goes here
    accounts.each do |account|
      AccountMailer.hello_message(account).deliver
      account.mark_hello_delivered!
    end
  end
end

job = MailJob.new(params["first"], params["second"])
Delayed::Job.enqueue(job)
```

Comment: Whoa. Let me wrap my mind around that for a minute. So this is not a `ActionController` or `ActiveRecord` child, but a standalone class that is initialized with my app? I'm going to need to load this file up in my `application.rb` right? I think I like it.

Comment: That's right. You don't need to require it in application.rb if it's in `app/**/*` since everything in there is auto-reloadable. Just make sure the class name matches the file name.

Comment: Note that the last two lines are what you would use from a controller action to enqueue a job of this class. They're not part of the job class itself, but only an example of how to use it.